# Somatoria de valor de um array?

Tags: javascript

Não estou conseguindo mostrar na tela a somatória de cada linha, os valores estão se somando junto com as outras linhas

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        var somatoria = [];
        var soma = 0;

        for(x = 0; x<7; x++){
            for (y = 0; y<5; y++){
                somatoria[y]= Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
                soma += somatoria[y]; 
            }
            document.write(somatoria+" = "+soma+ "<br>");
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a variável `var soma = 0;` no início do primeiro `for` para zerar a cada linha:

```js
var somatoria = [];

for(x = 0; x<7; x++){
   var soma = 0;
   for (y = 0; y<5; y++){
      somatoria[y]= Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
      soma += somatoria[y]; 
   }
   document.write(somatoria+" = "+soma+ "<br>");
}
```

Comment: Você conferiu essas somas de cabeça pra testar se está tudo ok?

Comment: De cabeça não, na calculadora do Windows.

Comment: Soma só as unidades, se a unidade do resultado for igual a unidade dessa soma das unidades, pode confiar!!!!